# Why do I segfault?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc

Here is my code, I'm getting a segmentation fault and I don't know why...
I'm creating a grid which `n` is its size, `tab` is an array which his type is cellule : a cell has 2 values. So I'm creating in the function `creer_grille` an array I `malloc` it (size can be 4 6 or 8) and I initialize the cells values with -1 and 0. Then in the following function I'm testing the `creer_grille` function.

```
typedef struct
{
    int val;
    int initial;
} cellule;

typedef struct
{
    cellule  *tab;
    int      n;
} grille;

grille  *creer_grille(int n)
{
    grille *g;
  int    i;

  assert(n == 4 || n == 6 || n == 8 && "Taille de la grille différent de 4,6 ou 8");
    g->n = n;
    g = malloc(sizeof(int) * (n*n));
        if (g->tab == NULL)
                exit(-1);
    for (i = 0; i < n*n; i++)
      {
        g->tab[i].val = -1;
        g->tab[i].initial = 0;
      }
      return g;
}

void detruire_grille(grille * g)
{
  free(g);
}

void test_creer_grille(){
    int i,k;
    for(k = 4; k <= 8 ; k+=2){
        grille * g = creer_grille(k);
        assert(g->n == k && "Problème dans le champ n de la grille");

        //Vérification que les cellules sont vides
        for(i = 0 ; i < k * k ; i++){
            assert(g->tab[i].val == -1 && "Problème : cellule non vide !");
            assert(g->tab[i].initial == 0 && "Problème : cellule initiale !");
        }
        detruire_grille(g);
    }
    printf("Test de la fonction creer_grille OK !\n");
}

int    main()
{
   test_creer_grille();
}
```

Comment: You probably want: `assert((n == 4 || n == 6 || n == 8 ) && "Taille de la grille différent de 4,6 ou 8");`

Answer (score 3):

```
g->n = n;
```

This is accessing an uninitalized value - invoking [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code. Move the line to after you allocate using `malloc`.

Also `g = malloc(sizeof(int) * (n*n));` is wrong you don't want `grille*` to point to a chunk which is allocated for `int`'s. because in case there is not enough memory there will be undefined behavior acessing memory out of your allocation.

```
g = malloc(sizeof(*g) * (n));
```

As you have allocated the `n*n` locations for storing `grille` you should access them by indexing

```
      for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
        // for some x
        g[i].tab[x].val = -1;
        g[i].tab[x].initial = 0;
      }
```

Again `g->tab[i].val = -1;` this is wrong because of the same reason pointed earlier. You have to allocate memory to `g[i].tab`. Otherwise it's undefined behavior. You have to allocate memory for `g[i].tab`.

```
   g[i].tab = malloc(sizeof *g[i].tab * someSize);
```

Also there is a flaw in your logic. First of all allocating `nxn` memory doesn't mean you have `nxn` grid. The method you followed will give you a contiguous chunk of `nxn` elements and that will not be of that use. (You can make a use of it but that's an overkill).

The best thing you can do is a jagged array and it's example is shown here.

Example code:-

```
grille  *creer_grille(int n)
{
  grille *g;

  g = malloc(sizeof *g * n);
  if( g == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr,"%s\n","Error in malloc");
    exit(1);
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    g[i].tab = malloc(sizeof *g[i].tab * n);
    if( g[i].tab == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error in malloc");
        exit(1);
    }
    g[i].n   = n;
    for(size_t j = 0; j < n; j++){
        g[i].tab[j].val = -1;
        g[i].tab[j].initial = 0;
    }
  }
  return g;
}
```

You have to `free` the dynamically allocated memory after you are done working with it. The `free` logic would be something like - you will first free the memory allocated in `tab` and then after all of those memory is freed, you will free memory allocated in `g`.